# Mix between block pricing and list pricing for CPQ

Tags: cpq, pricing

We want to setup in CPQ a mixed pricing between block and list, so that if a user buys from 1 to 5 licenses of our product the price will be 150, if they buy more than 5, the price per product is 25, so the total for say 7, would be 7*25.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use block pricing for this. Here is an example from Salesforce help: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000319897&type=1

First you need to ensure you have the Overage Rate field on the Block Price object

1. Navigate to the Block Price Object.
2. Create a New Currency Field.
3. Field Name: OverageRate (API Name: OverageRate__c)
4. Click Save.

Then you can set up block pricing with 2 blocks:

| Block Tier | Lower Bound | Upper Bound | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-5 units | 1 | 6 | $150 |
| 6 + units | 6 |  | $150 + $25/unit |